# Exporting to DWG using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, dwg

I am an architecture student with no experience with QGIS. However, I need some .dwg drawings of a town in Italy called Certaldo. I found detailed drawings for the town and had to download it as a .qgs file. I have the file open in QGIS and from the little reading I have done, the layers I am trying to export needs to be a vector layer in order to export it as a .dwg file. However it seems to be a raster layer.

How do I convert this raster layer into a vector layer?

Comment: You're going to have to either convert the dwg to vector format prior to importing or manually digitise the layer post import. Is the dwg already georeferenced?

Comment: welcome to GIS Stackexchange. At the moment your question doesn't make complete sense. A .qgs file is a QGIS project file which doesn't contain the data itself. Do you have layers in the layer list? What are they?

Comment: @MartinHügi Yes I have the layers in the layers list. However, they are all rasterized. One particular layer has all the data I need. It even has a legend relating to the information shown on the map.

Comment: @AndrewTice There is no dwg, just the rasterized layer containing all the map information I need. So I am guessing all this needs to be digitised?

Comment: @A.Ani...Whoops, sorry I read the question wrong, export as .dwg! It does sound like you're going to have to digitise. There's a number of questions already on here about automatically tracing building footprints...have a look for those. All the best!